# Python - turn string of list of dictionaries to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I have a string that looks like this:

```
'{"screen_name":"Brian","avatar":1},{"screen_name":"David","avatar":21},{"screen_name":"Teo","avatar":34}'
```

How can I make it a list of dictionaries?
I tried with json.loads, but it threw an error...

Comment: You need to add square brackets to the string, `'[{"screen_name":...}]'`

Comment: It doesn't represent a list in any notation. At best this is a tuple of dicts as a Python literal. For valid JSON or a Python list literal, it's missing the `[]`.

Comment: you can use `eval` (or better to use `ast.literal_eval`, definitely if the source is untrusted).  This will give you a *tuple* of dictionaries. If you must have a list, just convert that tuple to a list. But you should generally change whatever process is creating this sort of string to use an actual serialization format

Answer (score 1):

before trying `json.loads`, you have to make sure that is surrounded by square brackets.

You can achieve that by using `format` or `fstrings`, so you can do:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(f"[{original}]")
[{"screen_name":"Brian","avatar":1},{"screen_name":"David","avatar":21},{"screen_name":"Teo","avatar":34}]
```